# How to modify React classNames after `render` and before updating DOM?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app, I would like to process react components and modify `className`s before they are rendered to DOM. Is there any way to do that?

For example transform `<div className='bg-primary' />` to `<div className='background-blue' />`.

Comment: Can't use conditionals to change them in your code?

Comment: I want to do it in one place for entire app without changing all components.

Comment: why not use props to define which version/ global style you are using?

Comment: yes, but don't want to change anything in the app code. I just want to wrap it in something and do the transformation!